# Apps Script to automate treatment history creation

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api

I have an Apps Script from Google code. In this code I attempt to acomplish:

1. Have the code check a spreadsheet with URL provided, navigate to the page Base de Datos de Px.
2. It should check if inside the Expedientes Px folder with provided URL there is a subfolder for every patient row in Base de Datos de Px, the folder would have the same name as the patient.
3. If the folder does exist inside Expedientes Px, it will then create a spreadsheet copy from a template provided with URL.
4. Name the spreadsheet with "Historial de Tratamiento" + Nombre Px.
   Nombre Px is a column from Base de Datos de Px.
5. Once the file is create it it should copy some data from Base de Datos de Px on the new spreadsheet.

However, the code I have is not creating any spreadsheets. I ask Chat GPT to write the code for me and troubleshoot through some possibilities to no success.

1. Check if maybe the folders name and Nombre Px in Base de Datos de Px had different spaces or punctuations preventing the find of a exact match.
2. Share setting from files, but all have been set to editor for anyone with a link.

This is the code:

```
function getColumnIndexByName(columnName, headerRow) {
  for (var i = 0; i < headerRow.length; i++) {
    if (headerRow[i] === columnName) {
      return i;
    }
  }
  return -1; // Column name not found
}

function getFolderByName(parentFolder, folderName) {
  // Implement your logic to get the folder by name here
  // Return the folder if found, or null if not found
  // Example implementation:
  var folders = parentFolder.getFolders();
  while (folders.hasNext()) {
    var folder = folders.next();
    if (folder.getName().trim() === folderName.trim()) { // Trim and compare folder names
      return folder;
    }
  }
  return null;
}

function createTreatmentHistory() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('URL');
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Base de Datos de Px');
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  var folderId = 'URL';
  var destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);

  var templateSpreadsheetId = 'URL';

  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    var nombrePx = data[i][getColumnIndexByName('Nombre Px', data[0])];

    if (nombrePx) {
      var folder = getFolderByName(destinationFolder, nombrePx);

      if (!folder) {
        var formattedFolderName = nombrePx.replace(/\s+/g, ''); // Remove spaces from the folder name
        folder = destinationFolder.createFolder(formattedFolderName);

        var newSpreadsheet = DriveApp.getFileById(templateSpreadsheetId).makeCopy('Historial de Tratamiento' + nombrePx, folder);
        var newSpreadsheetId = newSpreadsheet.getId();
        var newSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(newSpreadsheetId);

        var tratamientosSheet = newSpreadsheet.getSheetByName('Tratamientos');
        tratamientosSheet.getRange('C1').setValue(data[i][getColumnIndexByName('ID Px', data[0])]);
        tratamientosSheet.getRange('C2').setValue(nombrePx);
        tratamientosSheet.getRange('E2').setValue(data[i][getColumnIndexByName('Sexo', data[0])]);
        tratamientosSheet.getRange('G2').setValue(data[i][getColumnIndexByName('Edad', data[0])]);

        newSpreadsheet.saveAndClose();

        // Move the spreadsheet to the created folder
        folder.createFile(newSpreadsheet);
        DriveApp.getFileById(newSpreadsheetId).setTrashed(true);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Check if maybe the folders name and Nombre Px in Base de Datos de Px had different spaces or punctuations preventing the find of a exact match.

Share setting from files, but all have been set to editor for anyone with a link

But none of those worked.

Comment: `var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('URL');` You can open a spreadsheet by Id:  [openById(id)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyidid), OR by URL: [openByUrl(url)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyurlurl). But you can NOT  use `openById('URL')`. Same applies for `getFolderById()` by URL, and `getFileById` by URL.

Comment: `I ask Chat GPT to write the code for me and troubleshoot through some possibilities to no success.` ChatGPT is notoriously unreliable, inefficient and unsuitable as a source of advice for scripting. With respect, it seems as though you have a list of things that you wish to achieve with a script but you have not tried to solve the problem yourself (nor troubleshoot the ChatGPT "code"). I strongly suggest that you learn how to write an apps script and then when you have a specific problem, open a new question focusing on that specific problem.